# How to use Huggingface GenerationMixin (or its beam search) with my own model?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, beam-search

Huggingface's use of a mixin keeps teasing me that this should be possible, but I can't find any clear documentation on exactly what the requirements are, or if the dependencies are just too much to make it worth it. [The central module](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/generation/utils.py) is literally thousands and thousands of lines, and I felt from studying it yesterday that I've learnt more about how to write beam search than I have about GenerationMixin. :-)

From reading the source I think the dependencies are `self.config` then `prepare_inputs_for_generation()` and `_update_model_kwargs_for_generation()`; also implicitly `forward()`. But I'm not sure that is everything. Nor what each should look like. And I think it may expect `forward()` to return data in a specific format.

To make the discussion specific, and generally useful, how could Huggingface's beam search be used with [minGPT](https://github.com/karpathy/minGPT), which has a `forward()` function that returns `logits,loss`. (It actually has its own `generate()` function that does the equivalent of Huggingface's `sample()` and `greedy_search()`, but no beam search support.)  Or [nanoGPT](https://github.com/karpathy/nanoGPT) if you prefer - they are identical in this area.

In the comments I said *It seems everyone's generate/beam search implementation is tied in closely with their transformer implementation...* and I still can't really see why everyone reinvents this wheel, and why there is no standalone open source beam search implementation, with a clearly defined interface. Going to throw a bounty at this question, to see if it helps.

Comment: I am honestly not sure what an acceptable answer should look like. You can of course implement it, but it depends on what your underlying model looks like. From a software engineering perspective, I am also not sure if it is worth the time, since external parties that implement Mixins from transformers are AFAIK out of hf's scope (i.e. they may not keep it backward compatible and change their interface anytime). 

TLDR: I am not sure If this question is generally useful in the current state. I might still answer over the weekend, but I am not sure.

Comment: @cronoik Thanks, that is partly what I'm trying to understand. It seems everyone's generate/beam search implementation is tied in closely with their transformer implementation... by making it a mixin, HF seem to have got closest to some independence. But as I said, maybe it is an illusion, maybe they are just teasing me :-)

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/q/74560753/841830 is the Tensorflow equivalent of this question. I imagine an answer here would answer that one too, as Huggingface supports it and PyTorch equally.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use huggingface code, what you're looking for is `generate` from `GenerationMixin` class, see [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/0a55d9f7376f72ad3ff296d4249840021b03bcc4/src/transformers/generation/utils.py#L1301C18-L1301C18)

So your options are either adapt the code to inherit from GenerationMixin, or copy the code over. Either way it depends on your model being huggingface-friendly so juts plugging in a random one without adjusting the code won't work.

If you don't necessarily want to use hface code, there's a bunch of very convenient implementations on github that are easier to adapt, for example [here](https://github.com/budzianowski/PyTorch-Beam-Search-Decoding/blob/master/decode_beam.py)

Comment: "it depends on your model being huggingface-friendly" That is my question: what exactly do I have to do to make my model huggingface-friendly, such that I can make use of `GenerationMixin`.

Comment: @DarrenCook tbh I'd suggest you use the second way, but if you want the first one, make sure it inherits the class `GenerationMixin` and take a look at how, for example, `T5ForConditionalGeneration` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I asked several chat bots but they generated non-sense answers. Apparently they cannot generalize beyond the Web.

By checking the code you would reach the `can_generate` method which has the following comment:

```
# Detects whether `prepare_inputs_for_generation` has been overwritten, which is a requirement for generation.
# Alternativelly, the model can also have a custom `generate` function.

if "GenerationMixin" in str(cls.prepare_inputs_for_generation) and "GenerationMixin" in str(cls.generate):
   return False
return True
```

So, you have two options, overwrite either `prepare_inputs_for_generation`  or `generate`.

The first option is suitable if you want to use one of the search strategies implemented in the `GenerationMixin` class and you have maybe a multi-modal model with different input requirement.

But if you have a different search strategy, like you want to generate XML and need to select next token in a way that ensures XML validity, you have to write your custom `generate` method. This is not a good design, there should have been a search or sample method that we could overwrite.

Also there is another abstraction `LogitsProcessor` which is used to change logit values before sampling. But the documentation is minimum and there are no example of custom usage.